# Writing on an SD Card wih an FPGA

Tags: fpga, sd

I will be using the following FPGA
https://store.digilentinc.com/nexys-video-artix-7-fpga-trainer-board-for-multimedia-applications/
I have a module who has 16 std_logic_vector (13 downto 0) outputs
The values of these outputs are changing every 50 Mhz on every rising edge of my FPGA_clock.
I want to store these datas on an SD CARD and be able to read back the data out of the SD Card.
But i don't know if it is possible to read and write on the SD CARD using the signals:
VDD
DAT2
DAT1
CMD
CLK
DAT3
DAT0
CARD_DETECT
Is there any document that explains how to control these signals to write and read on a SD CARD via an FPGA?
Thank you for your help[image]

Comment: You can find the SD and UHS specs at https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/pls/index.html  It sounds like you're looking for a phy level interface block, and probably a higher level driver or state machine. Is that accurate? I believe the Phy is essentially just a multi-bit SPI, but the spec would say for certain.

Comment: Thank you for the link, i still don't know what is a phy level interface block. All i want to do is write the data on the SD card and then after i stored all the data on the SD card i want the FPGA to be able to access the data an read it back

Comment: The Digilent doc says "For information on implementing the SD card controller, refer to the SD card specification available at www.sdcard.org". I suggest that should be your first step. The doc says the interface can support full SD speeds, so I would say yes, you can write and read from the SD card using your FPGA.

Comment: Your comments indicate you've not come to grips with how low-level the interaction with the SD card is that you'll have to implement! The card doesn't "just write data". It needs to be initialized, you need to read out the memory structure, and need to implement all the logic that takes care of the card when writing stuff to it - that can take variable time, might involve checksums, has to happen only when the card is ready, has to happen in specific chunk sizes... An FPGA is **not** a computer with dedicated SD card interface hardware and an operating system with a driver and a file system!

Comment: Thank you in fact i thought that we could access an SD card as we access a BRAM